# Custom Qt Widget instantiated but does not show

Tags: qt, widget, qt-creator

In Qt Creator I've dropped a custom widget onto my form, and it looks fine, but when I compile and run, only the form's default Qt widgets (slider, label, etc) show but not the plugin's widgets.

In the .pro file, the include path and the LIBS+= are pointing to the widget's header directory and .lib file respectively.

The widget does display if I progrmatically instantiate it:

```
cwidget *cw = new cwidget(); 
cw->show()
```

But this creates a new window with the widget rather than adding it to the correct position on the main window.

Isn't there a way to have custom widget objects in the form display automatically, just like all the qt standard widgets?

Comment: How did you "drop" the custom widget into your form?

Comment: The form.ui is part of the Qt creator project, so double clicking it, I can design the form by dragging any widget from the column of available widgets (including the custom one) onto the form.

Comment: Ok, so that means you're using QtDesigner as a WYSIWYG editor for the form layout. If you have your custom widget available in the list of widgets then you must have created a custom QtDesigner widget plugin. Have you checked that your plugin is working properly? Most specifically that your `CustomerWidgetPlugin::includeFile()` function is returning the correct header file? And also, have you checked the `setupUi()` function in the generated UI header class that your custom widget is being generated properly?

Comment: I placed the dll in the creator plugins folder, so not sure how to tell if it's working..

the icon for the widget just shows the Qt logo, and not a mini version of the widget itself.. however, when I drag it onto the form, it appears correctly. 

But after building, the generated .h file has the widget entries in setupUi():
(
        cw = new cwidget(centralwidget);
        cw->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("cwg"));
        cw->setGeometry(QRect(310, 310, 16, 16));
)

At runtime, does it look for the plugins' .h files or just the generated header/.ui file and the .lib file that was linked?

Answer (score 3):

First of all try this.

```
cwidget *cw = new cwidget(this); //for example in the MainWindow constructor
cw->show();
```

When you set parent this widget will appear in the MainWindow, not in the new window. Is it works?

Comment: Thanks that worked.  Since it seems to place it by default in the top left corner, it would be just a matter of scaling it and then moving it to the right position.

Comment: @BenNguyen If you want to use it as  I wrote in my answer than best way is to use layouts. Worst way is to use 'setGeometry()' method

Comment: Thanks, this is a good workaround if I can't get the form to display the widget automatically.   Strange since the generated setupUi is already creating the object and setting setGeometry with it.   Just doesn't make sense why it's not showing it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect your new widget to the window in some way. You can either directly set the main window as a parent using the constructor or the setParent(). A better way is to attach your widget to a layout of the window.

Comment: Thanks, since the standard qt widgets are automatically attached to the main window at runtime, I figured the same would be true for the custom widgets.  It seems the information in .ui file containing all the custom widgets properties (size/postion/etc) would serve no purpose.